# Rails helpers without @template.content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

there are another ways to create helpers instead of using `@template.content_tag` and `@template.concat` commands?

These look too verbose.

Actually I need to rewrite some helpers like text_field, radio_button, submit, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to generate HTML from your helpers, I assume?

You can simply generate strings using any method you want. If you call `html_safe` that will prevent the special characters from being escaped.

```
def header_helper
  '<div class="header">This is a test</div>'.html_safe
end
```

And in the template

```
<%= header_helper %>
<p>This is the content of the section</p>
```